# How many revolutions will it take to repeat original pattern?

Tags: statistics

I was wondering if anyone might have an answer (or a formula) for a question i have? Sadly, I am an art student, and not a mathematician, thus, my question....

I am trying to figure out the number of rotations it would take for the drive gear to make for the "pattern" to repeat itself.

The gears (in order) are 50 teeth, 57 teeth, 53 teeth, 60 teeth, 55 teeth, 58 teeth, and 52 teeth. The last gear (the 52 teeth gear) is attached to a parallel 13 teeth spur gear that drives a perpendicular set of gears via a 15 tooth spur gear. This second, perpendicular set is the same exact order and number of teeth as the first major set (50, 57, 53, 60, 55, 58, 52)

Any help at all is GREATLY appreciated! Thanks a million!

Comment: If you're an art student, perhaps yould provide a pretty drawing of the gear train? You can edit your question.

Comment: Oi! No need for snark, lass. Here the link to the video of the machine... https://m.youtube.com/#/watch?v=EXXb4SB9584